# "Mistaken" result of calculation. JAVA. So stuck

Tags: java

**Hello everybody.**
I'm stuck and don't understand why the code gives me back a "wrong" answer.

**My task:** to write a program which takes numbers and counts them until the user types "exit",
then the program prints out the summary of all digits which the user just inserted and stops.

I'm learning java online at the moment and don't know how to answer that:
when you type 1 or 2 or 3 numbers or more, it calculates and print the wrong result, or even the code can't be compiled and pops up an error.

*E.g.* you put 2 numbers and there is an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "exit"
>       at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
>       at JR.constructors.Solution.main(Solution.java:11)

---

*OR* 3 numbers, such as 2 + 3 + 4 and it prints 6 instead of 8.

Help me please!

And here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int sum = 0;
    while(true){
        int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        String s = reader.readLine();
        sum += a;
        if(s.equals("exit")){
            System.out.println(sum);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "exit" doesn't look like a number for `parseInt()`.

Comment: Follow the flow of data when you enter "exit". Where is it given to before the `s.equals("exit")` check.

Comment: May someone explain it more clearly please

Comment: Trace through your code with a debugger, or just using your finger to point to each line. You create your BufferedReader. You initialize `sum` to zero. Now you start a loop. Read a line - if no line is available it waits. Parse the line you just read as an Integer and assign it to `a` — if it's not an Integer you get a NumberFormatException. Now read another line into `s`. Note you haven't done a calculation yet. Add `a` to `sum`. Check if `s` is "exit" ... what if the second line you typed is a number? That number is compared to "exit", it is _never used_ in the calculation. etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone types anything other than a number `Integer.parseInt()` will fail and throw an error, So use *1* variable to get the input from the stream , first look and see if the user typed "exit" if not try to convert the string to an integer, make sure to put this in a try catch block to catch error if the user typed something invalid.

Comment: @Max — using only one variable will also fix the problem with your calculation being "mistaken"

Answer (score 1):

### Problems:

1. Using `reader.readLine()` twice.
2. Wrong placement of the exit criteria.

### Solution:

1. Remove `reader.readLine()` from within `Integer#parseInt`.
2. Place the exit criteria at the beginning of the loop so that the program can exit without trying to parse the word, `exit` which will throw `NumberFormatException` because this function can parse only integer strings.

   **Code:**

   ```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           int sum = 0;
           while (true) {
               String s = reader.readLine();
               if (s.equals("exit")) {
                   System.out.println(sum);
                   break;
               }
               int a = Integer.parseInt(s);
               sum += a;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   **A sample run:**

   ```
   2
   3
   4
   exit
   9
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The mentionned errors (exceptions) come from incorrect input parsing. You must make a clear distinction between reading a number and reading a String, or wisely catch exceptions when converting strings to numbers.

I'd propose a solution with `Scanner` instead (**simpler, clearer, less exceptions handling**).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    String inputStr = null;
    int sum = 0;

    // Attention: order of conditions matters
    while(!"exit".equals(inputStr) && scn.hasNext()) {
        if(scn.hasNextInt()) {
            sum += scn.nextInt();
        }
        else {
            inputStr = scn.next();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("SUM="+sum);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: needed to be BufferedReader as a rule of the task, but thanks!

Comment: Arf that was not mentionned. But you're welcome! Enjoy Java